# How do I create a framed box using stars as the frame and dashes on the inside?

Tags: c

I need to create a box made of stars that is filled with dashes on the inside.

This is for a homework assignment. I have a rough outline of code to use, but I am unsure how to get the stars into a box and dashes on the inside instead of stars.

#### GNU nano 3.2                                           1017.c

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    int main()
    {
        int sp, r, line;
        int k;
    
       for(line = 0; line <5; line++)
       {
           for(k = 0; k < 5; k++)
           {
               for(r = 0; r < sp; r++)
                   printf(" ");
               printf("*");
           }
           printf("\n");
       }
   
    return 0;
    }
```

This is what I should be getting:

```
*******
*-----*
*-----*
*-----*
*-----*
*******
```

But my actual output has been:

```
  *       *        *      *    *
      *       *   *          *  *
   *        * *          *    *
       * *       *   *       *
  *         *        *          *   *
```

Comment: What this `rand()` is doing there?

Comment: Hm. "[Rand](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rand)" may be the German word for border, but it has a different meaning in C. (Also, if your program is supposed to print dashes in the inner part, shoudln't there be a `"-"` somewhere?)

Comment: Ok, so you removed this line without changing anything else. Now what's `sp`? Please make an effort to understand your own program. 3 nested loops shouldn't be there for sure.

Comment: Yes there should be "-", but im not sure how i would word it in order for it to refer to just the inside of the box

Comment: There are no spaces in the output, so you can remove everything related to printing spaces.

Comment: `int main(void) { for(int x=0;x<6;x++) for(int y=0;y<8;y++) putchar( y == 7 ? '\n' : x%5 ? y%6 ? '-' : '*' : '*'); }`

Answer (score 1):

You need a condition expression to check whether you are filling a boundary or the interior. You need to check if it is the first row or last row, or first column or last column (those are your boundaries where you output `'*'`), otherwise you output out fille (`'-'`). Similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWS 5
#define COLS ROWS

int main (void) {

    int r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
        {
            if (!r || r == ROWS-1 || !c || c == COLS-1)
                putchar('*');
            else
                putchar('-');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/hboxfilledex
*****
*---*
*---*
*---*
*****
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (formatting is horrible because entering code on here sucks. But this code will work nonetheless):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_rectangle(int n, int m) 

{ 

int i, j; 


for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) 

{ 

for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) 

{ 

if (i==1 || i==n || j==1 || j==m)             

 printf("*");             

else

 printf("-");             

 } 

printf("\n"); 

 } 


}

int main() 

{ 

int rows = 6, columns = 7; 

print_rectangle(rows, columns); 

return 0; 

}
```

Comment: @ SavageGames24 Yup, but they made it easier recently. Just begin and end the code block with three back ticks. I'll leave it to you to copy/paste the code again to get the formatting cleaned up.